# unable to locate factory with name [default] [Subject]

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I just want some dummy data that I can loop out from my database but when I try to using the seeder I get this error:

```
unable to locate factory with name [default] [Subject]
```

The code I run is:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=SubjectSeeder
```

ModelFactory.php:

```
$factory->define(App\Subject::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'code' => $faker->str_random(3),
        ];
});
```

SubjectSeeder.php:

```
public function run()
{
    $subject = factory(Subject::class)->make();

    Product::create([
        'name' => $subject->name,
        'code' => $subject->code
    ]);
}
```

subject.php:

```
class Subject extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'code',
    ];
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SubjectSeeder.php:

```
$subject = factory(\APP\Subject::class)->make();
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by OddDream is correct.

Just to explain it more.

1. Your model/object might not be linked properly.

   `$subject = factory(\App\Subject::class)->make();`
2. Another reason is the cache. You might want to do something like.

   `php artisan config:clear`

   `php artisan config:cache`

Let me know if it helps you.

:)

Comment: iam sorry i did not respond to his post, yes that was the problem and it was already solved thank you

Answer (score 1):

If someone makes the same mistake as me, i tried just to define `state` factories, without default one:

```
$factory->define(\App\Model::class, function (Faker $faker) {
```